# How do link my preferences.xml to a tab in my TabLayout?

Tags: android

I have three tabs in my TabLayout and want one of them to be for settings/preferences. So I'm trying to implement the recommended Preference UI building block to add to my tab as a Fragment. So I've created the `xml` directory which contains a `preferences.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="text"
        android:title="text"
        android:summary="text"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Which I want to extend to my template activity when the settings tab is accessed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.zorgan.app.Find">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I currently open the chosen tab's activity via this code in my `Find.java`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

However in the third case in my switch statement, when I change `R.layout.fragment_settings` to `R.xml.preferences.`, it gives a red line error saying `Expected resource of type layout`. Any idea why it doesn't allow this XML file? How do I use my `case 3` to go to `R.xml.preferences` instead of a regular layout XML file?

```
    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {

            case 1: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find, container, false);
                break;
            }

            case 3: {
                SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                // what goes here?
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a [Preference fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment).

You don't need to call inflate view; instead you should be loading the preferences like this:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Create a new fragment called SettingsFragment , and for case 3 , use the fragment.

Comment: Not sure if i've done it right but i've added my code in my edit. If i've done it right so far, how do I actually call/start the `SettingsFragment` in case 3?